# Using calendar days as UITableView datasource in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm fairly new to iOS development and had a quick question. I've been using `UITableView's` in some sample application development for practice and noticed that the datasource tends to be some sort of Collection such as an `NSArray`. It appears that the reason behind this is so you can map the index of the current `UITableViewCell` to the proper index in the datasource.

So now I am finally getting to work on the project that I had wanted to make when I started out to learn `Objective-C` and iOS development. A calendar app that lists the days events in a `UITableView`. My question is, since I am accessing the events from an `EKCalendar` object in the `EKEventStore`, and have multiple calendars with varying events per day, how would you set that up with a `UITableView's` datasource? I had originally just created an `NSArray` of `NSDates` that spanned backwards three years from the current day and forward three years from the current day, then I could map the index of the table view to this as a datasource. That doesn't sound like the correct way to go about doing this, because what if the user needs to go forward more than three years? I'm assuming there's a more efficient manor or a better approach that to do this.

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        //Get calendar access from the user.
        [self initCalendars];

        DateUtility *dateUtility = [[DateUtility alloc] init];

        NSMutableArray *dates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        //Build array of NSDates for sharing with the View Controller
        //This seems like the incorrect way to do this...
        //Backwards three years
        for (int date = -(365*3); date < 0; date++) {
            [dates addObject:[dateUtility adjustDate:[NSDate date] byNumberOfDays:date]];
        }

        //Forward three years
        for (int date = 0; date < (365*3); date++) {
            [dates addObject:[dateUtility adjustDate:[NSDate date] byNumberOfDays:date]];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)initCalendars {
    //respondsToSelector indicates iOS 6 support.
    if ([self.eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
        //Request access to user calendar
        [self.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            if (granted) {
                NSLog(@"iOS 6+ Access to EventStore calendar granted.");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Access to EventStore calendar denied.");
            }
        }];
    } else { //iOS 5.x and lower support if Selector is not supported
        NSLog(@"iOS 5.x < Access to EventStore calendar granted.");
    }

    //Store a reference to all of the users calendars on the system.
    self.calendars = [self.eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];

    [self.eventStore reset];
}
```

This is the adjustDate method in the event you want to see what all of my code does.

```
- (NSDate *)adjustDate:(NSDate *)date byNumberOfDays:(NSUInteger)numberOfDays {
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    components.day = numberOfDays;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    return [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];
}
```

What is the best design pattern to use for trying to use data from multiple `EKCalendars` within the event store as a datasource to a single `UITableView`? How would you setup the dates of a calendar as a datasource, regardless of the number of events that particular day has, or regardless of the calendar being used?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a fairly decent approach to this that I have implemented, so I'll answer my question.

My datasource instances an array of NSDates that's spans 12 months. As I pull NSDate references from the datasource, it monitors the current index that is being used. When the index starts getting close to the lastObject in the array, the datasource model goes ahead and generates an additional 6 months worth of NSDates.

Since I am increasing the number of objects in my datasource (within my model) I added a BOOL property called setNeedsNumberOfItemsRefreshed. I then setup a KVO with my View Controller as the observer, observing the setNeedsNumberOfItemsRefreshed property. When I add items to the datasource, I set the setNeedsNumberOfItemsRefreshed = YES and my View Controller invokes reloadData on my table view which updates numberOfItemsInSection. Seems to work fairly well for me thus far.